# Unable to run Unix Commands using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java

I am using Windows and have installed Unix Utils from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/). The normal commands (such as `ls` and `cat`) work in **Windows CMD**, but when I try to run them using a `ProcessBuilder` in **Java**, I get this Error code: `Cannot run program "ls": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`.

My code is as follows:

```
        ....
        BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        commandLine = console.readLine();
        cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] commands = commandLine.split(" ");
        for(String command: commands){
            if(!command.equals(" ")){
                cmd.add(command);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(cmd.toString());

try {
                System.out.println("trying to run ls");
                ProcessBuilder pBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
                Process p = pBuilder.start();
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Invalid command.");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: You could try using `cmd /c ls`...?

Comment: or these commands are not on the path

Comment: Check the `PATH` env variable,  `echo %PATH%` in your java program.If unix utills are not there in your `PATH`, add them to your env and run your program again.

Comment: I added the necessary files from unixutils (/usr/local/wbin) into System32, and System32 is in the `PATH` env variable. Furthermore the commands all run properly in cmd.

Comment: I was following a lesson when I did that, but is there another alternative to installing the unix utils?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution, but I do not actually know if this is the best way to solve it.

I was following a lesson in which my professor told me to copy some necessary files from UnxUtils into System32.

This works when calling Unix commands on Windows cmd shell, but not through Java's `ProcessBuilder`. I added the JDK root into an Environment Variable with `JAVA_HOME` as its name, added `UnxUtils/bin` and `UnxUtils/usr/local/wbin` then restarted my IDE. It works now.